# transponer resultados mysql

Tags: mysql

tengo la siguiente duda, tengo estos registros de ejemplo en una tabla mysql

```
| Mes |Dni|Valor|
| Ene |11 | 10  |
| Ene |22 | 20  |
| Feb |11 | 40  |
| Mar |11 | 10  |
| Abr |22 | 10  |
```

Con esos datos quiero llegar a este resultado

```
|DNI|Ene|Feb|Mar|Abr|
|11 |10 |40 |10 | 0 |
|22 |20 |0  |0  |22 |
```

he intentado varias formas pero no logro "transponer" los resultados
quedo atento a dudas o consultas, muchas gracias

Comment: "he intentado varias formas".. cuales? no vaya a ser que te ofrezcan lo mismo que intentaste... es mas.. capaz intentaste lo que hay que hacer, que es crear una tabla PIVOT...

Comment: ¿Revisaste [estas preguntas en el sitio](/search?q=pivot+[mysql]+is%3Aquestion+-[laravel*]+-[php])?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo siguiente te puede ayudar a resolver tu problema:

```sql
select tablita.dni, 
       sum(case when tablita.mes = 'ene' then tablita.valor else 0 end) enero,
       sum(case when tablita.mes = 'feb' then tablita.valor else 0 end) febrero,
       sum(case when tablita.mes = 'mar' then tablita.valor else 0 end) marzo,
       sum(case when tablita.mes = 'abr' then tablita.valor else 0 end) abril
from (
values row('ene', 11, 10), 
       row('ene',22,20), 
       row('feb',11,40), 
       row('mar',11,10), 
       row('abr',22,10)
) tablita(mes, dni, valor)
group by tablita.dni
```

Básicamente lo que haces es usar `CASE` y `SUM` para acomodar las columnas según los valores de cada mes.

La salida es tal cual la que esperas, aunque hay un error en cómo esperas el mes de abril, no es 22 sino 10:

```sql
+-----+-------+---------+-------+-------+
| dni | enero | febrero | marzo | abril |
+-----+-------+---------+-------+-------+
| 11  | 10    | 40      | 10    | 0     |
| 12  | 20    | 0       | 0     | 10    |
+-----+-------+---------+-------+-------+
```